# Distribution of Data Within Hypersphere That Maximizes the Nuclear Norm?

Tags: eigenvalues, circular-statistics, norm

Suppose I have $N$ points in $\mathbb{R}^D$ such that for each point $x_n$, its L2 norm is at most 1:

$$||x_n||_2^2 = x_n^T x_n \leq 1$$

Assuming $N > D >> 0$, if I construct a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times D}$ where the $n$th row of $X$ is $x_n$, what distribution over $x_n$ maximizes the nuclear norm (also called trace norm) of $X$?

$$||X||_* := \sum_{r=1}^{rank(M)} \sigma_r(M)$$

I know that, in this setting, the nuclear norm is upper bounded by $\sqrt{ND}$, and I believe that the uniform distribution on the surface of the sphere achieves this upper bound. Is that correct? Do other distributions also achieve this upper bound?

Comment: How do you consider on the one hand a 'distribution' which results in stochastic variable behaviour, and on the other hand a maximisation of a 'norm' that does not incorporate how to deal with the stochastic behaviour? For example, two random points (N=2) distributed on a circle (D=2) will not have a nuclear norm that is constantly equal to $\sqrt{ND} = 2$.

Comment: In what sense can a *distribution* maximize anything that is a varying function of the random variable?  Are you perhaps asking for the *expectation* of the trace norm?  Are you assuming the $N$ points are independent or not?

Answer (score 0):

I get a larger norm when I select points from a distribution centered at the axes of the sphere.

An example computation is with the code below. (The one distribution will end up with a norm equal to $\sqrt{ND}$ but the uniform distribution is not)

```
set.seed(1)
n = 30

### n points from a uniform distribution on a sphere
phi = 2*pi*rnorm(n)
x = cbind(cos(phi),sin(phi))

### n points from a discrete distribution at four points
rows = cbind(c(0,0,1,-1),c(1,-1,0,0))
k = sample(1:4,n, replace =1)
y = rows[k,]

sum(svd(y)$d)^2 ### 60 = 30*2 = n*d
sum(svd(x)$d)^2 ### 59.64603
```

But this is just a single sample. The average of samples might be a different issue (the equality with $\sqrt{ND}$ in the above example is a coincidence). Is is the average that you are after?